# Rails: difference between placing stylesheets under 'assets' vs. 'public'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed stylesheets may be located in *either*:

- `app/assets/stylesheets`
- `public/stylesheets`

What's the difference, and why?

EDIT: I also realize that this location is totally customizable, but these are the most prevalent locations I've found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you go read about the "rails asset pipeline."  That should answer your questions...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

The short answer is that 'app/assets' uses the asset pipeline and 'public/stylesheets' is simply a static file.

Comment: One year back, it's crazy to realize that I understood so little about Rails.

Comment: can you give me a more detailed answer?